# Can't pause nano in terminal

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, signals

Trying to learn how to use terminal here.

So I can use ctrl-z to pause other processes, but for some reason it does not work in nano. Why that would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily done by masking the SIGTSTP signal:

```
#include <signal.h>

signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_IGN); /* disable ctrl-Z */
```

That's what nano is doing, apparently.

If you want nano to allow you for suspending it with ctrl-z you can put the line:

```
set suspend
```

into your `$HOME/.nanorc`.

Comment: Good, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Strange, I'm getting `Error in /Users/ccuk/.nanorc on line 1: Command "allow" not understood` When I try to use that

Comment: I think the edit got screwed up when the author edited this answer. I think the author meant to say to put `set suspend` in your ~/.nanorc, which is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Does not work in version 6.4. Regardless of this setting, emits: `To suspend, type ^T^Z`.

Comment: I now see `[ Mistakes in '/home/pknowles/.nanorc' ]` when opening nano. I'm guessing we should switch to [`bind ^Z suspend main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74008963/1888983) instead.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for a solution to this and the accepted answer didn't help me.

Setting `set suspend` in ~/.nanorc works!

http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nanorc.5.html

Comment: Does not work in version 6.4. Regardless of this setting, emits: `To suspend, type ^T^Z`.

Answer (score 6):

In newer versions of nano, the `-z` and `--suspendable` options have been removed. Suspension is now enabled by default, but only via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. To get back the familiar <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> behaviour, the following may be added to the `.nanorc` file in the home directory, to re-enable this feature for that user: `bind ^Z suspend main`. This can be achieved using the following command.

```bash
>>~/.nanorc echo 'bind ^Z suspend main'
```

The change can also be applied for all users by editing `/etc/nanorc` instead.

Comment: please vote this answer up, as all the other answers no longer work, and this one does.

SO needs a way to have old answers that no longer work to be flagged as outdated.

Answer (score 4):

If you enter `nano -z` it works as well.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work when you open up a new file like nano porkins.txt

Comment: No problem! :) Glad to help.

Comment: Actually, I found that nano -z doesn't work when you open a new file. So you have to type nano -z demo.txt to make it work with new file. But, couldn't have done it without you. Thanks again Jessica.

Comment: In version 6.4: `nano: unknown option -- z`

Answer (score -2):

if ctrl doesn't work then try using ctrl + x.

Comment: This exits recent versions of nano, maybe you made a typo?